# SQL, search for true, false or both

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to code an SQL search that can return TRUE, FALSE, or NEITHER.  While the code I currently have works, I do not like the fact that I had to copy and paste a lot of code, and was wondering if there was a way to reduce the amount of code here.

```
DECLARE @FYear int = 2017
DECLARE @FQuarter char(2) = 'Q2'
DECLARE @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET bit = NULL

IF(@FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET IS NULL)
    SELECT  FYear, 
            FQuarter, 
            IIF(FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = 'TRUE', 1,0) AS Financial_Goal_Met
    FROM    Finances    
    WHERE   (FYear = @FYear) 
            AND (FQuarter = @FQuarter)
ELSE
    SELECT  FYear, 
            FQuarter, 
            IIF(FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = 'TRUE', 1,0) AS Financial_Goal_Met
    FROM    Finances
    WHERE   (FYear = @FYear) 
            AND (FQuarter = @FQuarter)
            AND FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET
```

Comment: Just use the bottom query and change `AND FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET` to `AND FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET or @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = NULL`

Comment: TSql does not have a boolead data type - the bit data type will hold either 0, 1 or null, but not `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one query:

```
DECLARE @FYear int = 2017;
DECLARE @FQuarter char(2) = 'Q2';
DECLARE @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET bit = NULL;

SELECT FYear, FQuarter, 
       (CASE WHEN FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS Financial_Goal_Met
FROM Finances f  
WHERE (FYear = @FYear) AND (FQuarter = @FQuarter) AND
      (@FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET IS NULL OR FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET = @FINANCIAL_GOAL_MET);
```

For those not familiar with the `bit` type in SQL Server, `'TRUE'` is accepted for comparison, even though it is a string.